# SQL Query formater

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, color

Как в Visual Studio сделать расцветку SQL запроса в файле c# как на картинке?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я думаю, такое сделать нельзя, ибо в файле C# SQL команды чем являются? Верно, строкой (`string`), а строка, это единое значение, которое имеет единый цвет. Хотя, может и есть сторонние плагины, которые парсят строку, но не думаю (ибо бесполезно).

Comment: [This Visual Studio 2010 extension adds basic SQL syntax highlighting (keywords, functions and variables) to string literals](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fbdegroot.SQLSyntaxHighlighting) - этот для vs2010, так что ищите нужный вам extension для вашей версии VS

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Но когда создаешь Regex и в него передаешь строку то она раскрашивается.

Comment: @Qwerty Хм, не обращал на это внимание. Ну значит там есть встроенный парсер для этого, ищите тогда расширение, но это действительно ведь бесполезно, ибо так просто SQL мало кто использует, ибо есть, например EF, который превращает любой запрос в простой `.Where(...).Select()` и так далее. Так что, мой вам совет, откажитесь от затеи использовать так на прямую SQL запросы, это плохо и чревато последствиями.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, категорически спорное утверждение :) на ef в кровавом энтерпрайзе далеко не уедешь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел подходящее расширение `Sql Tools`